# Where is the error in this sql statement?

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an sql error when attempting to use this statement:

```
   CREATE TABLE users (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY,
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
        );
```

The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR' at line 1
```

Using

> MySql V5.7.26

Comment: Please post the SQL error that you receive.

Comment: Just add `KEY` in your `PRIMARY KEY`.. See this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a6ac1befa80e8b192a9b25ecb2bacadb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add **KEY** in **PRIMARY** like **PRIMARY KEY**, you have missed the `SQL` syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE users 
       (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the query.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
        );
```

In your query **KEY** is missing after **PRIMARY**.

Answer (score -1):

Run this query then, u will get no syntax.

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        );
```

You place the `PRIMARY KEY` identifier on a separate line

Comment: [Is "try this" bad practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196187/172661) "Try this" is a suggestion, not an answer. Suggestions belong in comments.

Comment: I received the same error when I tried this (did not downvote)

Comment: Hmm, i don't see any errors running this query on my machine. what is your default storage engine? you can check by running this query `show variables like '%Engine%';`